# bash を、ユーザー固有の設定を読み込まないで起動させることはできるか

Tags: bash

特にローカルの環境において、ユーザーホームディレクトリ直下の bash 設定ファイル (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`) を、よく編集することになります。結果、編集していく過程で、手元のシェルから触るシステムの挙動が怪しくなったりします。

このような場合に、今自分が編集したりしている、ユーザー固有のプロファイルスクリプトのみを読み込まないようにして、 bash を起動できたらよいな、と考えました。

#### 質問

bash で、ユーザーホームディレクトリにあるプロファイルのみを読み込まず、つまりシステムのプロファイル(`/etc/profile` 系)のみを読み込む形で、 bash を起動させることはできるでしょうか？
というのも、ホームディレクトリ直下のプロファイルを一時的にすべて .bk などに mv するのは、、できなくもないけれども、手間だと考えており。。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まずは`man bash`でマニュアルを確認することをおすすめします。

[How to start a shell without any user configuration? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9357464/2322778)

`--noprofile`と`--norc`を使う方法があるようです。

```
$ bash --noprofile --norc
```

ただし`--noprofile`は`/etc/profile`も読み飛ばしてしまうので、`--rcfile`オプションで明示的に読み込ませるTipsも紹介されています。

```
$ env -i bash --rcfile /etc/profile
```

Comment: `env -i bash --rcfile /etc/profile` が、自分の欲しかったものの様子です。

Answer (score 0):

オフトピかもしれませんが、編集した設定ファイルを読み込まないことで なぜ 問題が解決するのかよく分かりませんでした。個人的には、編集したら 別Shellで 変更内容をテストするのが 良いと思います。

```
$ vim .bashrc
$ bash -l (サブプロセスでbashを起動)
$ (変更した内容をテスト)
$ exit (サブプロセスを終了)
$ . .bashrc (読み込む)
```